# Python - позиция курсора в файле во время прохождения по файлу циклом for

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть файл `any_file.txt` с неким набором строк (через перенос строки).

`f.readline()` перемещает курсор в файле на конец строки, которую он вернул (это легко проверить, вызвав `f.tell()` между каждым вызовом  `f.readline()`

Но куда перемещается курсор, если пробежаться по файлу циклом `for`?

Если внутри цикла вызвать метод `f.tell()`, возникнет исключение `OSError: telling position disabled by next() call`

Вот пример кода:

```
with open("any_file.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for x in f:
        print(x)
        y = f.readline()
        print(y)
```

В первой итерации `x` - первая строчка, `y` - вторая

Во второй итерации `x` - треться строка, `y` - четвертая

Правильно ли я понимаю, что когда мы пробегаемся циклом `for` по файлу, то курсор перемещается в конец строки на каждой итерации?

Comment: Проход по файлу через for и чтение через readline работают одинаково по сути. Курсор после каждой итерации перемещается на следующую строчку. Оба способа чтения вместе лучше не совмещать.

Comment: А что вы практически хотите получить из этого знания? Вам зачем-то нужно знать точное положение курсора?

Comment: Практической пользы данное знание, возможно, не несет. Просто пытаюсь более углубленно познать особенности языка Python. И, все-таки, непонятно, почему метод f.tell() падает с ошибкой внутри цикла.

Comment: Потому, что его отключил next (). Файл ждет, что итератор будет в качестве параметра, как понимаю. А tell - явно не он. Если интересно, что происходит, то надо в генераторы и итераторы углубляться.